# mouse_event vs real mouse event

Tags: c#, mouseevent, keyevent, mouseclick-event, cursor-position

1. Is there a difference between a **real mouse click** (by hand) and execution of the **click from code** (by [mouse_event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646260%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in c#)?
2. Similarly, is there a difference between the real moving the mouse cursor and setting Cursor.Position?

**If there is a difference:**

1. How to recognize source of that event?
2. There is a way to simulate a **mouse click** / **cursor move** as if it came from a **mouse or keyboard driver**?

---

**Edit1:** Code sample added for @Marco Forberg.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern void mouse_event(uint dwFlags, uint dx, uint dy, uint cButtons, uint dwExtraInfo);

    Button button;

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        button = new Button();
        button.Text = "Click";
        button.Location = new Point(50, 50);
        button.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 20);
        button.Click += button_Click;
        Controls.Add(button);

        Button simulate = new Button();
        simulate.Text = "Simulate";
        simulate.Location = new Point(50, 100);
        simulate.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 20);
        simulate.Click += simulate_Click;
        Controls.Add(simulate);

    }

    void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(sender);
    }

    void simulate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Point location = button.PointToScreen(Point.Empty);
        Cursor.Position = new Point(location.X + (button.Width / 2), location.Y + (button.Height / 2));

        mouse_event(0x02 | 0x04, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: A real click could get intercepted and may cause more than one event to be thrown, running an event will only fire the one event.

Comment: Yes for example. Left mouse click should be created by 2 events: DOWN 0x02 and UP 0x04.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference if you create proper Event arguments. The only way to find out that event is from "machine" is to analyze moments.

Comment: So if I change Cursor.Position and run mouse_event randomly in time or will simulate the behavior of the human hand, it is impossible to identify the origin event?

Answer (score 3):

@Garath,
[MSLLHOOKSTRUCT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644970%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) contain a `LLMHF_INJECTED` flag witch is set when the event come from a call to `mouse_event` function.

You can retrieve this information by using `SetWindowsHookEx` as I explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26301949/361177).

Answer (score 0):

The difference between a real click on a control and programmatical call to your mouse event handler should be the `sender` prarameter.

For real mouse clicks you receive the control that was clicked as sender. when you call an event handler programmatically you should provide a *sensible* sender

Comment: I know what you mean, but the question was about the origin of the event rather than an object which event was executed.

Comment: what do you mean by "origin". the `sender` parameters holds/should hold the element where the event came from

Comment: For me it is not important on which the control was done event. Whether I click with the mouse manually (by hand), or I use mouse_event (programmatically), sedner is identical in both cases.

Comment: cann you please show me a code snippet how you call the event?

Comment: ah looks like i missunderstood you. thought you called the handler and not simulate a click

Answer (score 0):

I'm also trying to do this in C# but within an injected c# dll, hosted clr.
A friend of mine suggested reading this article http://pastebin.com/rj4YcW4C

I'v tried mouse_event, PostMessage,SendMessage,SendInput and Cursor.Position.
All ignored but i beleave that article has the answers we both seek.