# Send virtual mouse clicks that are ignored by GetAsyncKeyState()?

Tags: c#, windows

I've been experimenting and searching all day, and can't for my life figure out how to do this.

As the title reads, I want to be able to send mouse clicks that are ignored by something like GetAsyncKeyState().

Basically what I'm doing:

```
//While physically holding left mouse button...
while (GetAsyncKeyState(0x01) != 0)
{
    //left mouse button virtually down (obviously already is down the first loop)
    mouse_event(2, 0, 0, 0, 0); 

    Thread.Sleep(100);

    //left mouse button virtually up
    mouse_event(4, 0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

Now, the while-loop stops because I virtually lift the button, so what I'm asking for is an alternative to mouse_event/GetAsyncKeyState (or some parameter I don't know about), so I can manipulate key states without that affecting the actual state.

For example, I've been able to do this in AutoHotkey using **Send {LButton up}** and **GetKeyState("LButton", "P")**.

Any ideas?

Comment: BTW, why do you want to do that !!!

Comment: Well I'm doing an auto-clicker that requires weird timings, and I really want it to click the keys I'm physically pressing. It's mostly just for experimental reasons. Your answer really pushed me in the right direction, so thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[MSLLHOOKSTRUCT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644970%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) contains `LLMHF_INJECTED` and `LLMHF_LOWER_IL_INJECTED` flags. Maybe you should take a look at it.

The code below is just an empty form with a timer, configured to be "On" and call "TimerOnTick" every seconds.

When you click, the output is "497, 361, 0" when the timer *click* the output is "497, 361, 1"

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Syracuse
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private const int WH_MOUSE_LL = 14;
        private static LowLevelMouseProc _proc = HookCallback;
        private static IntPtr _hookID = IntPtr.Zero;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnLoad(e);
            _hookID = SetHook(_proc);
        }

        protected override void OnClosed(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnClosed(e);
            UnhookWindowsHookEx(_hookID);
        }

        private void TimerOnTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //left mouse button virtually down (obviously already is down the first loop)
            mouse_event(2, 0, 0, 0, UIntPtr.Zero);

            Thread.Sleep(100);

            //left mouse button virtually up
            mouse_event(4, 0, 0, 0, UIntPtr.Zero);
        }


        private static IntPtr HookCallback(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
        {
            if (nCode >= 0 && MouseMessages.WM_LBUTTONDOWN == (MouseMessages) wParam)
            {
                var hookStruct = (MSLLHOOKSTRUCT) Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof (MSLLHOOKSTRUCT));
                Console.WriteLine(hookStruct.pt.x + ", " + hookStruct.pt.y + ", " + hookStruct.flags);
            }

            // Todo create OnMouseUpExEvent, OnMouseDownExEvent witch provide MSLLHOOKSTRUCT informations.

            return CallNextHookEx(_hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);
        }

        private static IntPtr SetHook(LowLevelMouseProc proc)
        {
            using (var curProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
            using (var curModule = curProcess.MainModule)
            {
                return SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, proc, GetModuleHandle(curModule.ModuleName), 0);
            }
        }

        private delegate IntPtr LowLevelMouseProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        #region Enum & Struct
        private enum MouseMessages
        {
            WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x0201,
            WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x0202,
            WM_MOUSEMOVE = 0x0200,
            WM_MOUSEWHEEL = 0x020A,
            WM_RBUTTONDOWN = 0x0204,
            WM_RBUTTONUP = 0x0205
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        private struct MSLLHOOKSTRUCT
        {
            public POINT pt;
            public uint mouseData;
            public uint flags;
            public uint time;
            public IntPtr dwExtraInfo;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        private struct POINT
        {
            public int x;
            public int y;
        }
        #endregion

        #region Extern
        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern void mouse_event(uint dwFlags, uint dx, uint dy, uint cButtons, UIntPtr dwExtraInfo);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, LowLevelMouseProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        private static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hhk);
        #endregion
    }
}
```